# Functional relationship between two quantities

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, st.statistics, convex-optimization

Let $\mu \in \mathbb R^n$ and let $\Sigma$ be a positive-definite matrix of order $n \ge 2$. Fix $t \ge 0$ and define $\alpha(\mu,\Sigma,t) > 0$ by

$$
\alpha(\mu,\Sigma,t) := \sup_{\|w\| = 1}\frac{1}{\|w\|_\Sigma}\varphi\left(\frac{w^\top \mu - t}{\|w\|_\Sigma}\right),
$$

where $\|w\|_\Sigma := \sqrt{w^\top \Sigma w}$ and $\varphi$ is the Gaussian pdf. Also define $\beta(\mu,\Sigma,t) \ge 0$ by
$$
\beta(\mu,\Sigma,t) := \inf_{\|z\| \le t}\|z-\mu\|_{\Sigma^{-1}}.
$$

> **Question.** *Is there any functional relationship between $\alpha(\mu,\Sigma,t)$ and $\beta(\mu,\Sigma,t)$ ?*

### Example: isotropic case

Suppose $\Sigma = I_n$, the identity matrix. Then

$\alpha(\mu,\Sigma,t) = \varphi(r_\star)$, where
$$
\begin{split}
-r_\star := \inf_{\|w\| = 1}|w^\top \mu - t| &= \inf_{\|w\| = 1}\sup_{s \in \{\pm 1\}}s(w^\top \mu-t) = \sup_{s \in \{\pm 1\}}-st+\inf_{\|w\| = 1}sw^\top \mu\\
& = \sup_{s \in \{\pm 1\}}-st-\|\mu\|=t-\|\mu\|,
\end{split}
$$
if $\|\mu\| \ge t$, and $r_\star = 0$ otherwise. That is, $r_\star = (\|\mu\|-t)_+$.

On the other hand, one computes
$$
\begin{split}
\inf_{\|z\| \le 1}\|z-\mu\|
&= \begin{cases}
0,&\mbox{ if }\|\mu\| \le t,\\
\|t\mu/\|\mu\|-\mu\| = |t-\mu| = \|\mu\|-t,&\mbox{ else}
\end{cases}\\
&=(\|\mu\|-t)_+ = r_\star.
\end{split}
$$

We conclude

> $\alpha(\mu,I_n,t) = \varphi(\beta(\mu,I_n,t))$.

Comment: What is $z$ in the definition of $\beta$? Also, what do you mean by a "functional relationship"? That one of them is a function of the other?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Typo, fixed. Yes that's what I meant by functional relationship. I've also included a worked example when $\Sigma=I_n$. Also, I posted the question here by mistake (as this is not really research-level math); I thought I was posting on SE. Please let me know if I should move this to SE.

Comment: Even your own calculation for $\Sigma=I$ shows that there is no functional relationship or, you may say, only a restricted functional relationship. But then you need to somehow qualify your general question.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Maybe I'm missing something in your comment, but my worked example actually shows that $\alpha = \varphi(\beta)$ in the special case when $\Sigma=I_n$. This is an explicit functional relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, even when $\Sigma=I$, we have
$$I_1(t,\mu):=\inf_{\|w\|=1}|w^\top\mu-t|=(t-\|\mu\|)_+ \tag{1}\label{1}$$
(think of large $t$), whereas
$$I_2(t,\mu):=\inf_{\|z\|\le t}\|z-\mu\|=(\|\mu\|-t)_+ \tag{2}\label{2}$$
(think of large $\|\mu\|$).

So, there is no functional relationship between your $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

**Details:**

*Details on \eqref{1}:* We have $\{w^\top\mu\colon\|w\|=1\}=[-\|\mu\|,\|\mu\|]$. So, $I_1(t,\mu)$ is the distance from $t\ge0$ to the interval $[-\|\mu\|,\|\mu\|]$. So, \eqref{1} follows.

*Details on \eqref{2}:* Clearly, $\|z-\mu\|\ge0$. Also, $\|z\|\le t$ implies $\|z-\mu\|\ge\|\mu\|-\|z\|\ge\|\mu\|-t$, so that $\|z-\mu\|\ge(\|\mu\|-t)_+$ and hence
$$I_2(t,\mu)\ge(\|\mu\|-t)_+. \tag{3}\label{3}$$
If now $\|\mu\|\le t$, let $z:=\mu$. Then $\|z\|\le t$ and $\|z-\mu\|=0=(\|\mu\|-t)_+$, so that $I_2(t,\mu)\le(\|\mu\|-t)_+$. If $\|\mu\|>t$, let $z:=t\mu/\|\mu\|$. Then $\|z\|=t\le t$ and $\|z-\mu\|=\|\mu\|-t=(\|\mu\|-t)_+$, so that again $I_2(t,\mu)\le(\|\mu\|-t)_+$. So, in view of \eqref{3}, \eqref{2} follows.

*Details on the absence of a functional relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$:* If $\|\mu_j\|=j$ for $j=1,2$, then $I_1(0,\mu_j)=0$ but $I_2(0,\mu_j)=j$. So, $I_2$ is not a function of $I_1$.

If $t_j=j$ for $j=1,2$, then $I_2(t_j,0)=0$ but $I_1(t_j,0)=j$. So, $I_1$ is not a function of $I_2$.

So, there is no functional relationship between $I_1$ and $I_2$. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are functions of $I_1$ and $I_2$, respectively, we conclude that there is no functional relationship between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Indeed, there was an error in my calculations. Thanks!